# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: concat surname

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new with vue and trying to create a filter , I have create filter successfully with just data element but when I try to create with inline argument it gives me a above error . I have also try with string instead of variable but it's not working.

My filter like this

```
 Vue.filter("concat", (value, surname) => {
      return value + surname;
    });`
```

and component like this

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ firstName | concat surname}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "FilterComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: "Alex",
      surname: "Johnson",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `surName` vs `surname` - they are different?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use filter like this. If you want to pass surname as an argument to your filter you can do this (val will be firstname in the function):

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1> {{ firstname | concat(surname) }} </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data () {
    return {
      firstname :  "FirstName",
      surname : "LastName"
    }
  },
  filters: {
    concat : function (val, surname) {
      return val + surname // will return full name
    }
  }

};
</script>
```